# Setting default value in Trove hash map

Tags: java, hashmap, trove4j

How do I set the default value (returned when the key doesn't exist) for a TLongDoubleHashMap collection. It returns 0 by default, I would like it to return NaN.

I found this in the documentation:

> Returns the value that will be returned from `get(long)` or `put(long, double)` if no entry exists for a given key. The default value is
>   generally zero, but can be changed during construction of the
>   collection.

But I have found no way to set the value during construction.

Comment: What version of trove are you using ?

Comment: And please link to that quote in the documentation.

Comment: Link to quote: http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TLongDoubleMap.html#getNoEntryValue()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [this constructor](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TLongDoubleHashMap.html#TLongDoubleHashMap(int,%20float,%20long,%20double)):

```
public TLongDoubleHashMap(int initialCapacity,float loadFactor,long noEntryKey,double noEntryValue)
```

For example:

```
TLongDoubleHashMap map = new TLongDoubleHashMap(5, 0.5f, Double.NaN, Double.NaN)
```

Comment: Thank you. This wasn't in the documentation, but it is in the source code. I fixed the arguments in the answer as well.

Comment: It is in the docs : http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TLongDoubleHashMap.html